# How to sync onPremisesSamAccountName with Moodle user profile?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, moodle

I'm currently trying to add a custom user profile field and set it through oAuth2 services. I'm running Moodle 4.1.5.

I created the user profile field in Moodle with a short name, a name, a description and I set no to "required?", "locked?" and "unique?"

Then I added a user field mapping in OAuth2 services pointing to "onPremisesSamAccountName" and linking it to my new "profile_field_xxx" entry.

I checked in Azure and onPremisesSamAccountName and this field contains the right value.

I tried to delete a specific OAuth2 user account on Moodle then logged in using this account but the new field isn't filled in. Any idea why?

Another way to do it would be to use a script that would check if a given user exists in Moodle and if so, to set this new field but then I'd like to be sure not to mess with the Moodle DB. If I use such a script, would it be right to set only 'mdl_user_info_data.data' in the DB?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to test the login

Go to Site admin > Plugins > Authentication > Manage authentication > OAuth 2 > Test settings

Then click on the icon for Azure

It should display the values coming from Azure